# Why can't I find the server that is already using the 3306 port

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have already uploaded a question about this previously, but have a more specified one now. The error log in `xampp` says that there is another mysqld server using the port and I thought it had to be the `MySQLWorkbench` that I had installed previously because that had a database linked to `3306` using localhost. So I went into the config file and changed it to `3307` and then deleted the database connection several times.

This also didn’t do anything, so I uninstalled the whole server and program.

Still however, there is no way I can access the cloned repo and its definitely something simple I just cannot figure it out. 
These are the errors I get from `xampp`

> 2018-10-02 13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP
>   port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. 2018-10-02
>   13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server
>   running on port: 3306 ? 2018-10-02 13:46:23 2156 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: On which OS are you - Linux, Windows, Mac?

Comment: I'm using windows

Answer (score 0):

On windows you could use the tcpview.exe from the [Syinternals Suite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite) to find out which program uses (LocalPort) port 3306.